# dynamic multi input form field with bootstraper and laravel

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to have a dynamic multi input form field looking like this using laravel's Bootstrapper:

http://www.bootply.com/xnSS5NtHZM

where if the user presses the plus button those 2 fields will appear again underneath. In the `store()` method of my resource controller I'm saving the entire gizmo as json into the database.

I was hoping I could achieve this using (mostly) [bootstrapper](http://bootstrapper.eu1.frbit.net/) and simple jquery. It's not hard to do it quick and **dirty** but I'm trying to get a clean solution which I don't have.

Current code I have using bootstrapper:

```
{{
    ControlGroup::generate(
        Form::label('links', 'URLs'),
        [
            ['input' => ['type' => 'text', 'link_title', 'Title']],
            ['input' => ['type' => 'text', 'link_value', 'URL']],
        ]
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the basic concept. It uses jQuery clone method to get a copy of the HTML data and then appends it below.

http://www.bootply.com/9Jn9Uc8clj#

Comment: I got that far, I was trying to get it done with bootstrappER for laravel. Thanks either way